# How to get the character between a character and a space

Tags: c#

I have an application that gets a parameter of a certain SQL query.

How will I get the characters between **@** and ***space***?

Example: `Select Name From SomeTable Where Id=@ID Group By Name`

so the output would be: **ID**

I am using the following code but it only extract characters after **@**. In the above example it extracts: **ID Group By Name**.

```
strParamName = sqlQuery.Substring(sqlQuery.IndexOf('@') + 1);
```

Comment: Before we answer this, can you explain **why** you need to do this?

Comment: From your example it looks like you're doing something wrong. You shouldn't get SQL parameters' name this way.

Comment: Do you have your query as `string`  or as `SQLCommand`?

Comment: Hi to all, thanks for the comments. Yes my query is a string.I have a multi line textbox and allowing user to input sql in it. Then I would like to get the parameter.

Comment: It is more efficient to use string methods than regex.  In this case it is probably a toss up if it is better to use string (which takes 3 instructions like my solution) than a one instruction regex.  I like regex, but there are times it should be used and times when it shouldn't be used.  Too many times people recommend regex when it should not be used.

Comment: @Zhyke It would be awesome if you could show us more of your code. The only reason I could imagine this kind of code being used is if you are writing your SQL in a way that is open to SQL Injection. And that is a **very** bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is might be wrong approach in your case.

You can also achieve this via [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string sql = "Select Name From SomeTable Where Id=@ID Group By Name";

string result = Regex.Match(sql, "(?<=@)[^ ]+").Value;
```

Pattern `(?<=@)[^ ]+` means the following:

`(?<=@)` – positive lookbehind for `@` character,

`[^ ]+` – matches between one and unlimited times for non-whitespace () character.

Comment: Thanks. I choose this one since he explain it in detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
            string sqlQuery = "Select Name From SomeTable Where Id=@ID Group By Name";
            int startIndex = sqlQuery.IndexOf('@') + 1;
            int length = sqlQuery.Substring(startIndex).IndexOf(' ');
            string strParamName = sqlQuery.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of weird that you need to do this. So I warn you that you might be doing something wrong.

Anyway, here's a solution that uses regex:

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourSQLString, "^.+@(\\w+) .+$");
var result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```